# ng-model value must be a date object

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am building a CRUD app in angularjs material. So when I wantto add a new user the birthday input must be a  `<md-datepicker>` tag.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="add.user.BirthDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

This is the HTML tag.

But when I want to edit the user it occurs me an error that the model must be a date

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="edit.user.BirthDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

This is for edit and i call the fuction in the dialog because there must be the update of the user

```
////EDIT USER

//POP UP
$scope.showEdit = function (ev, user) {
 $mdDialog.show({
    controller: SampleController,
    templateUrl: 'app/main/sample/edit.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
    locals: {
      user: user,
      //map: map,
      editUser: editUser
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'edit'
  });


  //FUNC
  function editUser() {



    $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: 'http://192.168.23.65/DetyreAPI/api/Client/UpdateClient',
      data: {
        FirstName: user.FirstName,
        LastName: user.LastName,
        BirthDate: user.BirthDate,
        Address: user.Address,
        Latitude: user.Latitude,
        Longitude: user.Longitude
      },

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }


    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

      $mdDialog.hide();
      $scope.showUpdateAlert_Success();


    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $mdDialog.hide();
      $scope.showUpdateAlert_Error();
    });
  }



}
```

And also there is the function and dialog to add a new user

```
///ADD NEW USER

//POP UP
$scope.showAdd = function (ev, user) {

  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: SampleController,
    templateUrl: 'app/main/sample/add.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
    locals: {
      user: user,
      addUser: addUser
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'add'
  });
}

//FUNC
function addUser(value) {



  $scope.user = {

  };




  $http({

    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.23.65/DetyreAPI/api/Client/AddClient',
    data: value,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }


  }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    console.log(response.data);
    if (response.data.message === 'Ju shtuat nje kontakt me sukses!') {
      $scope.showData($scope.user);
      $mdDialog.hide();
      $scope.showAddAlert_Success();
    } else {
      $scope.showAddAlert_Error();
    }

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $mdDialog.hide();
    $scope.showAddAlert_Error();
  });

}
```

Comment: Your `edit.user.BirthDate` is probaly not a valid date object. Can you please share the value of that model?

Comment: Which type of date object you are assigning to date type in edit ?

Comment: i just update it

Comment: @HimeshSuthar i think it may be a string

Comment: `Error: The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: string` @Red @HimeshSuthar thats the error when i click to the edit icon

Comment: Show us your json. A date object should look like this: `Fri Sep 21 2018 11:33:42 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)`

Comment: `{
 "FirstName": "Iva",
 "LastName":"Sauli" ,
 "BirthDate":"1995-06-07",
 "Address":"Rr.Fortuzi, Ap11",
 "Tel":"0694791125", 
 "Latitude": "49.12312",
 "Longitude": "27.123213",
 "Active" : true
}` 
thats the json to add user from postman @Red

Comment: `{
  "Id": 1,
  "FirstName": "Iva",
  "LastName": "Sauli",
  "BirthDate": "1995-06-07",
  "Address": "Rr.Fortuzi",
  "Tel": "0694791125",
  "Latitude": "47.234",
  "Longitude": "27.434",
  "Active": true
}` 
and thats the json to edit

Comment: `value = {FirstName: "Mick", LastName: "Root", BirthDate: Fri Sep 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), Address:..... `
this is how it looks with debugger

Comment: See, thats the problem. Your date is not a valid date object `1995-06-07`. Convert it to a valid date using `new Date('1995-06-07');`

Comment: I am trying to do this thing now but it occurs me an error when I try to create a new user
The message is that BirthDate is required to add a new user, because i need to change the ng-model at datepicker input

Comment: `var Birthday = new Date(value.BirthDate);
      var date = Birthday.toLocaleString();
      console.log(date);`

Comment: So how can I update the ng-model in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `add.user.BirthDate` model is not a valid *date  object*. Your model value is: `1999-01-01` while a valid *date object* looks likes this

```
Fri Sep 21 2018 15:06:23 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)
```

So to convert your model to a valid *date object* you can do the following.

Create a custom directive which will convert the date to a *date object*

```
.directive('mdDatepicker', function () {
  function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    // This will format the model
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(valueFromInput) {

      // Format displayed value in timestamp format and store it to ngModel
      return new Date(valueFromInput);
    });
  }
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link,
    restrict: 'EA',
    priority: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: `response: Object
config:
data:
Address: "tirana"
BirthDate: Thu Sep 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
__proto__: Object
FirstName: "Mick"
LastName: "Root"
Latitude: 41.32
Longitude: 19.36
Tel: "304-0961809"
__proto__: Object
headers: {Content-Type: "application/json", Accept: "application/json, text/plain, `

this happens when i add a new user after debugging
and it looks like date is okay